# sum of product over decreasing range

Tags: python, pandas, math, vectorization

I am implementing a small Python application to measure returns of a trading strategy. The function that computes the return takes the following imputs:

- a Pandas' dataframe containing the close prices
- a Pandas' series of booleans representing buy signals
- a Pandas' series of booleans representing sell signals
- a float representing the trading fees as a percentage of the initial capital

This is what the data looks like:

```
>>> df.head()
            open  high   low  close  volume
date                                       
2015-01-02  5.34  5.37  5.11   5.21  108469
2015-01-05  5.21  5.26  4.85   4.87  160089
2015-01-06  4.87  4.87  4.55   4.57  316501
2015-01-07  4.63  4.75  4.60   4.67  151117
2015-01-08  4.69  4.89  4.69   4.81  159294
>>>
```

```
>>> buy.head()
2015-01-02     True
2015-01-05    False
2015-01-06    False
2015-01-07    False
2015-01-08    False
dtype: bool
>>>
```

---

Without taking into account the fees, this is the formula to compute the ratios:

[image]

Where `C` is the initial capital and `ri` is the return of one buy/sell trade.

This can easily be easily implemented using a vectorized implementation:

```
buy_sell = df[(buy==True)|(sell==True)]
prices = buy_sell.close
diffs = prices - prices.shift()
ratios = diffs / prices.shift()
return ((ratios + 1).product(axis=0))
```

---

When it comes time to take into account the fees, I end up with the following formula:

[image]

Where `f` is the trading fee.

This could easily be implemented using loops but is there a way to do this with a vectorized implementation?

I am not a math expert but maybe the product being dependant on the summation indices prevents this? I tried looking this property online but can't seem to find anything. Maybe I am not formulating the question properly since I am lacking the technical jargon.

Any thought on this would be appreciated :)

---

## Edit

From DSM's answer, the solution is to perform a 'cumulative product' on the reversed series of ratios. This gives me the following solution:

```
def compute_return(df, buy, sell, fees=0.):

    # Bunch of verifications operation performed on data

    buy_sell = df[(buy==True)|(sell==True)]
    prices = buy_sell.close
    diffs = prices - prices.shift()
    ratios = diffs / prices.shift()

    cum_prod = (ratios + 1)[1:][::-1].cumprod()

    return ((1 - fees) * (ratios + 1).product(axis=0) - fees * cum_prod.sum())
```

Comment: Can you add some data and expected results to this question?

Comment: Is this tick data? What is the time component? Might be helpful if you posted the first few rows as text

Comment: @sundance why would the time component matter? doesnt matter if calculating weekly returns or daily returns

Comment: Just added screen shots of the data structure. Data is indexed daily but like @RafaelC mentioned, the time component or even the data itself is not really important, it is more about the feasibility of vectorizing such a formula.

Comment: It is better using for loop here .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one isn't so bad, I don't think.  From a `ratios` like

```
In [95]: ratios
Out[95]: 
date
2015-01-02         NaN
2015-01-05   -0.065259
2015-01-06   -0.061602
2015-01-07    0.021882
2015-01-08    0.029979
Name: close, dtype: float64
```

we have (where here we're only concentrating on the 'new' second term):

```
def manual(rs):
    return sum(np.prod([1+rs.iloc[j] for j in range(i, len(rs))]) 
               for i in range(2, len(rs)))
```

and

```
def vectorized(rs):
    rev = 1 + rs.iloc[2:].iloc[::-1]
    return rev.cumprod().sum()
```

that is, all we need to do is take the sum of the cumulative product taken in the *reverse direction*, from end to start.

This gives me:

```
In [109]: manual(ratios)
Out[109]: 3.07017466956023

In [110]: vectorized(ratios)
Out[110]: 3.07017466956023
```

(I didn't pay much attention to worrying about whether we should be using 2 or 1 as the offset here, or putting in the `f` factor -- those are easy changes.)

Comment: Mmh I see... I didn't know about the `cumprod()` method but it seems like it is solving my problem pretty nicely! Being a Pandas method, I suppose its implementation is vectorized?